# Синхронная загрузка данных

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Я новичок в PHP и JS.
Пишу некоторый скрипт, который передает запросы на два api. 
Только проблема в том, что один api быстро возвращает ответ а второй не очень(~15-30сек).

Соответственно ответ с первого API я вывожу в один DIV, ответ второго во второй. 
Сейчас скрипт ждет ответа от двух запросов и потом выдает страницу пользователю, выходит то примерно секунд 30 пользователь просто смотрит в белый экран и ждет ответа.

Сейчас все написано на php. Логика примерно следующая.

```html
<?php
//файл для работы с API
require_once('./libs/class.php'); 

// Если ничего не передали
if(empty($_POST['search']) ) 
    //одали пустую форму
//если заполнили форму
elseif(!empty($_POST['search'])){ 
  //вызвали api, получили ответ и отдали пользователю. 
}
?>
```

И это слишком долго. Как асинхронно выполнить второй запрос? Понимаю что с помощью js, но как не понимаю.

С Уважением, Waik/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Делаем 2 отдельных асинхронных запроса:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({ // отправляем асинхронный запрос
    url: "/api1.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: { search : $('#search').val() } // берем данные для поиска
  }).done(function(data) {
    $( '#div1' ).html(data); // вставляем результат
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: "/api2.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: { search : $('#search').val() }
  }).done(function(data) {
    $( '#div2' ).html(data);
  });

});
</script>
```

На бекенде делаем 2 отдельных скрипта api1.php и api2.php